# Check if an array contains all elements of another in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics, swift2

I want to write an extension for array to check if an array contains all the elements of another array, in my use case it's string objects but I keep get:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'T.Generator.Element' to expected argument type '@noescape _ throws -> Bool'
```

in the line `self.contains(item)` the error in about `item`

here is my code:

```
extension Array {
    func containsArray<T : SequenceType where T.Generator.Element : Equatable> (array:T) -> Bool{
        for item:T.Generator.Element in array{
            if !self.contains(item) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have required that the sequence elements are `Equatable`,
but they are unrelated to the array elements. Therefore

```
 if !self.contains(item) { ... }
```

does not compile.

What you probably want is to require that the sequence elements have the 
same type as the array elements (and that should be `Equatable`):

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func containsArray<T : SequenceType where T.Generator.Element == Element> (array:T) -> Bool {
        for item in array {
            if !self.contains(item) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

If you need the method for array arguments only and not for
general sequences then you can simplify the declaration to

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func containsArray(array: [Element]) -> Bool {
        for item in array {
            if !self.contains(item) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

which can be shortened to

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func containsArray(array: [Element]) -> Bool {
        return !array.contains { !self.contains($0) }
    }
}
```

As @AMomchilov said, `contains()` does a linear search, so this
has `O(M*N)` complexity where `M` and `N` are the length of 
the two arrays. You could define a specialization for the case
that the elements are `Hashable`, and do the membership check
against a `Set`:

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func containsArray(array: [Element]) -> Bool {
        let selfSet = Set(self)
        return !array.contains { !selfSet.contains($0) }
    }
}
```

Whether this is faster than the previous method or not would depend on both
array sizes and also on the element type (how "expensive"
is it to compare elements).

Comment: Note to OP: This can be sped up a lot if a set is used. `.contains` does a slow linear search. This solution overall has quadratic time complexity.

Comment: @AMomchilov: Yes (if the elements are `Hashable`).

Comment: @AMomchilov so what do you suggest ?

Comment: The param to `isSubsetOf(_:)` can be the array itself, not need for a set. I'm curious how the performance of the two compares

Comment: @AMomchilov: Yes, but converting `self` to a set first *may* be an improvement if self is a large array with duplicated element. Generally I assume that it depends on the size of both arrays. For small arrays the linear without set conversion may be faster.

Comment: @MartinR A good implementation would iterate the sequence and check element membership against the set, rather than the other way around. I'll have to play around with it later

Comment: @AMomchilov: Isn't that what `Set(array).isSubsetOf(Set(self))` does? It takes the array parameter and checks membership against the receiver (self). – But anyway, the *question* (as I understand it) was why the given code does not compile, not about the fastest method.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, but only after doing an additional pass to build the set. It would take extra space, too. It's all fairly trivial, but I reckon answers like these should be the best they can be for future people coming I'm an copy/pasting

Comment: @AMomchilov: But there is no best one-fits-all solution. If `array` has 1,000,000 elements but only 10 *distinct* elements, then creating a set and checking membership of those 10 only might be faster than checking the membership of 1,000,000 array elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117332/discussion-between-amomchilov-and-martin-r).